# Decoding HTML character codes in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

How can I fix special characters like `&#39` in the value of an `input`?

I have `String DisplayName = "Test'S"` in my model, but my view displays it as `Test &#39;S` instead of `Test'S`. I've tried to use `Encode` and `Decode`, but neither of these have worked.

```
@Html.FormFieldFor(x => x.DisplayName)
```

Model:

```
public string DisplayName { get; set; }
```

Comment: I removed the references to JS and jQuery as they're not relevant to the problem; you're outputting the value from server side logic. Also, what is the logic in `FormFieldFor`? That's not a standard method, and how it encodes values is likely the cause of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, try looking up HTML helpers for the Razor engine and which one might fit your problem the best. [This](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/mvc/html-helpers) is one good resource that I have found to be useful when trying to render a view.